# Loop in Javascript to display DB Values

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am a python developer and new to javascript and ajax . I am creating a pie chart that displays DB values.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/dashboard/document/',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{
              csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response.result);
                $.each(response.result, function (item) {
                  console.log(item);
```

I have fetched my DB values using pymongo and it is stored in `console.log(response.result);`Now i need to print in `console.log(item);` using looping . How to use ?

Comment: can you show op of `response.result` ?

Comment: If you are new to JS, then consider starting with core JS and skipping the jQuery. You can use fetch for this now. Can you create a small example in a jsFiddle or something? It's hard to digest with only this amount of code: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: @Swati op of response.result : [ 518, 418, 188, 118 ]

Comment: simply do `$.each( response.result, function(item,value) { console.log(item+ " "  +value);  });`

Answer (score 0):

> i need to print in console.log(item); using looping . How to use ?

You can probably skip the jQuery if you are new to JS. (the language has come a long way and doesn't really need it often anymore : )

```
const exampleArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

exampleArray.forEach( function(thing) {
    console.log('thing: ', thing);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/h2fcb54g/